# utf8_encode() not able to convert properly few non-English/Diacritic characters

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, ansi

I have very weird situation. following text in my csv file and file shows as ANSI encoding on notpade++.
[image]

Œœ
Ÿ
654123 áÁàÀâÂäÄãÃåÅæÆçÇéÉèÈêÊëËíÍìÌîÎïÏñÑóÓòÒôÔöÖõÕŒœúÚùÙûÛüÜÿŸ

And following are my sample code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$handle = fopen("unicode.csv", "r");


while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== FALSE)
{
    $cur_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($line) ; 
    if($cur_encoding == "UTF-8" && mb_check_encoding($line,"UTF-8")) 
    {
        echo "\r\n UTF-8".$line; 
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "\r\n encode UTF-8".utf8_encode($line); 
    }
}?>
```

issue with code which i have found:

1. not able to detect the encoding.
2. two characters are missing. (Œœ and Ÿ)

Please help me to find why these two characters are missing.
another strange behaviour is that it show the character in Chrome but not in FF or IE 
**Note:** I am able to read successfully if i convert encoding to UTF-8 using Notepad++. so please do not suggest this solution. 
[Get the csv file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Z-uh4QnInsTDlLa0JWV2dBSVE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You want to display "Œœ Ÿ 654123 áÁàÀâÂäÄãÃåÅæÆçÇéÉèÈêÊëËíÍìÌîÎïÏñÑóÓòÒôÔöÖõÕŒœúÚùÙûÛüÜÿŸ", right?

Comment: yes, for now it is not getting display the mentioned characters as I mentioned. if this will start working then I have to make sure its getting save in db properly as well but that is not the goal for now. And these are three different line in my csv. 1.Œœ. 2. Ÿ and 3 654123 áÁàÀâÂäÄãÃåÅæÆçÇéÉèÈêÊëËíÍìÌîÎïÏñÑóÓòÒôÔöÖõÕŒœúÚùÙûÛüÜÿŸ

Comment: 1) Are you in control of the encoding of this file? If so, just safe it as UTF-8. If not… 2) ANSI doesn't mean anything, you need to know the specific codepage it's saved as. Then `iconv` from that specific codepage to UTF-8. Never bother with "detection". 3) If you need help identifying the specific code page, take a hex editor, look at your file in hex, compare which codepage your character encodings align with. (Or just try a bunch of different encodings with `iconv` until it looks okay.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file is encoded in Codepage 1252 a.k.a. MS-ANSI a.k.a. WINDOWS-1252 a.k.a. Windows Latin 1. To convert it to UTF-8:

```
echo iconv('CP1252', 'UTF-8', file_get_contents('unicode.csv'));
```

Comment: awesome! it worked. trying to find out what I have done wrong for my question down ovtes :(. anyways my doubt is how to figure out the "CP1252" you have used and what if I this file encode changes then will my same code will work always and it will not mess up with non English characters in file?

Comment: I have followed my advice from my own comment above to figure out the correct encoding. And no, if the encoding changes, obviously it will break. You need to know what a file is encoded in, which requires that the encoding doesn't randomly change.

Comment: as your previous comment; to identify the codepage first then use `iconv`. But in my case client mostly create csv from excel and save as csv which always ANSI encoding(which one? you have already mentioned) he can also create UTF-8 encoding csv file from notepad++. bottom line is client does not care about any such encoding. so in that case 1. what is the best approach to successfully read as UTF-8. 2. and Why using utf8_encode() was not able to encode those two characters only that I have mentioned.

Comment: +Q-3.How to decide the code page when file contain different characters from two different CP.

Comment: If you don't know the source encoding, the only reasonable thing is to ask the user. E.g. convert from some encoding to UTF-8, show the result to the user, ask them if it looks okay. Repeat until you have found the correct encoding. - `utf8_encode` converts from one specific "Latin 1" encoding to UTF-8, which happens to be the wrong one. There are a plethora of extremely similar "Latin" encodings which just differ in a few characters.

Comment: So there is no general solution to identify for all type of encodings​ and convert it to utf-8. In this case, forcing the client to always use utf-8 file is the best solution :).  And as per your last comment I didn't​ get how to decide the  code page if your file contains non English character from multiple CP. Thanks.

Comment: It cannot. If you're saying your file contains mixed encodings, it's simply completely effed up. Or it uses one of those terrible pseudo-standards which embeds controls codes somewhere in the middle signalling when code pages are changing… good luck parsing that stuff, you'll need a dedicated library for that. – Usually the entire file uses one and only one encoding, and you need to find the right encoding where all the bytes in the file map to the expected characters. You might want to read my primer on encodings: [What You Need To Know About Encodings…](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($line, array( 
    'UTF-8', 'ASCII'
));

var_dump(iconv($encoding, 'UTF-8', $line));exit;
```

Comment: checked, skipped first line then prints second correctly and again from third line shows "Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string" this message and print nothing

Comment: Try again with `iconv($encoding, 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $line)` and show the output. Or change iconv to `mb_convert_encoding($line, 'UTF-8', $encoding)`

Comment: still for third and fourth line it shows " iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string"

Comment: it is worse with mb_convert_encoding shows "Warning: mb_convert_encoding(): Illegal character encoding specified" and also all diacritic characters shows as question mark.

Comment: i have attached the csv file.